# Laravel - Using css on auth blade templates

Tags: css, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a little problem on my Register / Login form that I created via php artisan:make auth. I want to use those templates but my CSS doesn't work on them.

I use gulp and sass, my welcome page take my CSS and I just cut/paste and modify the path to my form templates.

Here is the basic template (register.blade.php). You just need to pay attention to the link, beacause I didn't touch the form.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('../../../public/css/app.css')}}">
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I don't know where is the problem, I use the same asset on my welcome page. My Editor says the path is the good one.

I'm here for more details and have an happy new Year full of code :)

Comment: Seems like this is Razor, not PHP

Comment: Please forget eveyrone, I found it i think ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL::asset` will points to `/public` folder. Try following path

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css')}}">
```